# Space between div tags

Tags: css, html

ok so ive been trying and seraching forums to understand how i can get rid of the space between my divs for example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVNrE.png (my website currently) i would like to remove the space between the footer and the disclaimer

my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Testimonials</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"
        />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <center>
            <div id="header"></div>
            <table width="70%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td width="40%">
                        <img src="images/woodslandscapinglogo2.jpg" width="400" height="124" alt="woods landscaping logo">
                    </td>
                    <td width="60%"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </center>
        <!-- END OF HEADER -->
        <!-- NAV BAR -->
        <div id="container">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="contactus.html"><span>Contact us</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="testimonials.html"><span>Testimonials</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html"><span>Gallery</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span>About us</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="last"><a href="woodslandscaping.com.au"><span>Home</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF NAV BAR -->
        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <div id="secondcontainer">
            <div id="content" style="width:60%;height:500px;float:left;">
                <center>
                     <h2>About us</h2>

                    <hr>
                     <h4>Here at Woods Landscaping, We provide the highest quality landscapes with all the newest and most efficient techniques. There is no job that is too big or small for us, as we have done large areas of schools, to just front and backyards and we do this at great affordable prices.
    We can provide a range of landscapes that can include:
    <ul><li>Paving</li>
    <li>Decking</li>
    <li>Retaining walls</li>
    <li>Water Features</li>
    <li>Irrigation</li>
    <li>Instant Turf</li>
    <li>Synthetic Turf</li>
    <li>Garden Lighting</li>
    <li>Rock Walls</li>
    <li>Earth Works</li>
    <li>Concreting</li>
    <li>General Soft Landscaping</li>
    <li>Maintenance Service</li></ul>
    So take your pick and call now for a free quote!
    Remember, there is no job too big or small that we can’t handle.
    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="images" style="width:40%;height:500px;float:left;">
                <img src="images/brighton-1.JPG" alt="" width="298" height="172">
                <img src="images/croydon-2.JPG" alt="" width="298" height="172">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF CONTENT -->
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <div id="footer" style="height:30px;">
            <h3><br>
    Ferntree gully 3156 VIC // abn. 47402024689 // p. 043 359 7007 // e. daniel@woodslandscaping.com.au</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF FOOTER -->
        <!-- DISCLAIMER -->
        <div id="disclaimer" style="height:20px;">
            <h5><br>© 2013 Woods Landscaping, Inc. All rights reserved. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h5>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF DISCLAIMER -->
    </body>

</html>
```

and my css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Capriola);
body
{
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   margin: 0 0 10px;
   background-image:url('images/background.jpg');
}
h1
{
   /* main grey heading*/
   font size: 15pt;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   color:#999999;
   text-align: left;
}
h2
{
     /* main gray heading*/
    font-size: 15pt;
   font-family:  Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   color:#999999;
   text-align: left;



}
h3
{
     /* smaller footer writing*/
   font-size: 6pt;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
   color:#4D4D4D;
   text-align: center;
}
h4
{
     /* main writing*/
   font-size: 10pt;
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-weight: 400;
   color:#999999;
   text-align: left

}
h5
{
     /* smaller disclaimer writing*/
   font-size: 6pt;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
   color:#999999;
   text-align: right;
}
td 
{
vertical-align:bottom;text-align:left;
}
#header 
{
    width: 70% ;
    background-color:#FFF;

}
#nav {

    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    background-image: url('images/linkbar.png');
    }
#nav li {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 40px; }

#nav li a {
   display: block;
   padding: 8px 15px;
   color:#ffffff;
   font-family:Trebuchet MS, "Helvetica", sans-serif;
   font-size: 0.75em; 
   text-align: ;
   text-decoration: none; 
        }
#nav li a:hover {
        color:#17AF49;
        background-color: #ffffff;
         }
#container{
    width:70%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;
    }

#secondcontainer{
    width:70%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    }

#content 
{
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    margin-top:0;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#images
{
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    margin-top:0;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#footer {
    background-color:#808080;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
}
#disclaimer {
    background-color:#4D4D4D;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
}



</style>
```

Comment: The screenshot of your website is super small. Reupload it to imgur instead.

Comment: Have you tried using margin-top: -1em (or whatever negative value) on the disclaimer

Comment: What happens if you change the margin statements in your css for #disclaimer and #footer to `margin: 0 auto`? Also: bad idea to use header tags for regular content. That's what paragraphs are for.

Comment: "margin-top: -1em" fixed the problem thankyou very much!

Comment: You have `margin: 0 0 10px;` for body and `margin-left: auto ;margin-right: auto ;` for disclaimer and footer so set `margin:0px` for both footer and disclaimer will solve it,.

Comment: @user1577114 that's not a very good solution, the right answer is to remove the margin from the heading tag inside #discalimer

Answer (score 1):

The space comes from the `<h5>` tag inside the `#disclaimer` which browser's add a default margin to, add this to your CSS

```
#disclaimer h5{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 mate, but wouldn't it be better to just make `margin-top: 0px;`? just in case other margins are required.

Comment: @Harry it will probably be better to set both top and bottom to 0, those are the ones added by browsers, in this case I didn't notice the OP having any margin declarations on the headings so I assumed that wouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

You've to set a `margin:0` to your H3 and H5 tags and use the margin properties to place your headers in the div.

Moreover, using `<br>` to insert spaces is kinda bad. Browsers don't give the same size to the new line inserted by this tag and results can be messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
h5
{
-webkit-margin-before: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be to remove the top/bottom margins from the `h3` and `h5` within `footer` and `disclaimer` respectively as such:

```
#footer h3, #disclaimer h5 {
    margin:0 auto; /* auto reflects the settings you've already defined */
}
```

Q. Have you considered restructuring the HTML to be more standards friendly and consistent across browsers?